How to properly do a "not equal" string comparison in an array, and then delete the element in bash
I am attempting to do a != string comparison of the last three characters of each string element in an array, then delete the element if it is not equal, but it is not producing the expected results. I am sure my code is incorrect, so I am looking for some guidance on how to correct.
I have tried two examples which use both "==" and "!=" to test my code, as follows:
Array:
array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t)


First run "=="

    for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        chomp=${array[i]: -3}
        echo chomp: $chomp
        if [[ $chomp == "foo" ]] || [[ $chomp == "bar" ]]; then
            echo "i: $i, element: ${array[i]}"
            delete=${array[i]}
            echo ${array[@]/$delete}
            array=( "${array[@]/$delete}" )
        fi   
    done
    array=( "${array[@]}" )
    echo "First run: ${array[@]}"

Output: (code works as expected, foo/bar elements deleted - but this is not what I want)
chomp: foo
i: 0, element: 8669648574foo
86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t
chomp: 45u
chomp: bar
i: 2, element: 231649bar
86696485745u 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t
chomp: 9a1
chomp: foo
i: 4, element: 8594792682foo
86696485745u 23164919a1 859479268209t
chomp: 09t
First run:  86696485745u  23164919a1  859479268209t # expected result

Second run "!="
    for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        chomp=${array[i]: -3}
        echo chomp: $chomp
        if [[ $chomp != "foo" ]] || [[ $chomp != "bar" ]]; then
            echo "i: $i, element: ${array[i]}"
            delete=${array[i]}
            echo ${array[@]/$delete}
            array=( "${array[@]/$delete}" )
        fi   
    done
    array=( "${array[@]}" )
    echo "Second run: ${array[@]}"

Output: (code not working as expected)
chomp: foo
i: 0, element: 8669648574foo
86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t
chomp: 45u
i: 1, element: 86696485745u
231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t
chomp: bar
i: 2, element: 231649bar
23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t
chomp: 9a1
i: 3, element: 23164919a1
8594792682foo 859479268209t
chomp: foo
i: 4, element: 8594792682foo
859479268209t
chomp: 09t
i: 5, element: 859479268209t

Second run: # no output, deletes all elements.

Note: I also tried using unset array[$i], but I exceeded post size so deleted those examples.
Q: How do I delete the array elements that do not equal foo/bar?

Use && instead of || (and have a look at De Morgan's laws)

See "Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?". Also, array=( "${array[@]/$delete}" ) doesn't delete any elements, it just deletes the string in $delete from each element; this replaces the element you're trying to delete with an empty string, and can also delete that string from any other elements that happen to contain it as a substring. Use declare -p array to see what array actually contains at the end.

@Gordon, Interesting. This never occurred to me, thanks! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work; see my next answer please.

@pmf, thanks for the link, very informative.

unset array[$i] doesn't work in general.  It should be unset "array[$i]" (or unset 'array[i]').  See Bash Pitfalls #57 (unset unquoted array element).  Shellcheck finds this problem, and many other common problems.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

Does this answer your question? Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?

"Unfortunately, it still doesn't work; see my next answer please." - This is not how the site works. The purpose of a question here is to ask a question, not to get your code working. It's your responsibility before posting to do basic debugging work to isolate a single problem to ask about. The underlying problem here is exactly what @GordonDavisson pointed out. Anything else is a separate question.

Playing with array under bash
0. Preamble
Care using bash as a programming language! If you plan do work on big entries, maybe some filter could be more efficients.
For sample:
mapfile -t array < <(grep -v '\(foo\|bar\)$' < <(/bin/yourCommand -args))

will populate your $array variable from the output of yourCommand, after deleting lines ended by foo or bar.
And ask yourself if you need to store whole array in a variable, or if you may have to pass this output as a stream to any next command...
1. Quick drop in (submited) array
shopt -s extglob

array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t)

array=(${array[@]/%*([0-9])bar})
array=(${array[@]/%*([0-9])foo})

declare -p array

declare -a array=([0]="86696485745u" [1]="23164919a1" [2]="859479268209t")

Revert job, deleting all but not bar nor foo:
Sorry, miss readed...
shopt -s extglob

array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t)

toDel=(${array[@]/%*([0-9])bar})
toDel=(${toDel[@]/%*([0-9])foo})
toDel=("${toDel[*]}")
array=(${array[@]/#?(${toDel// /|})})

declare -p array

declare -a array=([0]="8669648574foo" [1]="231649bar" [2]="8594792682foo")

2. Using unset in a loop:
Note: for matching multiple variation of same variable, you'd better use case switches, instead of multiple == whith || or &&!
array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t)
for i in ${!array[@]};do
    case ${array[i]: -3} in
        foo | bar ) unset "array[i]" ;;
    esac
done

declare -p array

declare -a array=([1]="86696485745u" [3]="23164919a1" [5]="859479268209t")

Notice the index keys: 1, 3 and 5, instead of 0, 1 and 2.
Then, to invert the job:
array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t)
for i in ${!array[@]};do
    case ${array[i]: -3} in
        foo | bar ) ;;
        * ) unset "array[i]" ;;
    esac
done

declare -p array

declare -a array=([0]="8669648574foo" [2]="231649bar" [4]="8594792682foo")

3. Using associative arrays
This solution is very quick as there are no loop and more robust than first purpose.
array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 85942foo 859479268209t)
printf -v sStr '[%q]+=%%q\  ' "${array[@]/#*([0-9])/_}"
printf -v sStr "$sStr" "${array[@]}"
unset "aArray"  # If already exist...
declare -A "aArray+=($sStr)"
unset "aArray[_foo]" "aArray[_bar]"
newArray=("${aArray[@]% }")
declare -p newArray

declare -a newArray=([0]="23164919a1" [1]="859479268209t" [2]="86696485745u")

But if, instead of unset aArray[_foo] aArray[_bar] you
array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 85942foo 859479268209t)
printf -v sStr '[%q]+=%%q\  ' "${array[@]/#*([0-9])/_}"
printf -v sStr "$sStr" "${array[@]}"
unset aArray  # If already exist...
declare -A "aArray+=($sStr)"
declare -a newArray="(${aArray[_foo]% } ${aArray[_bar]% })"
declare -p newArray

declare -a newArray=([0]="8669648574foo" [1]="85942foo" [2]="231649bar")

With strings that contain spaces:
array=('Some word.' 'Foo bar baz' 'String ended by foo' 'Hello world' 
       'String ended by bar' Singles words 'Another string ended by foo' )
printf -v sStr '[%q]+=%%q\  ' "${array[@]##* }"
printf -v sStr "$sStr" "${array[@]}"
unset 'aArray'
declare -A "aArray+=($sStr)"
unset 'aArray[foo]' 'aArray[bar]'
newArray=("${aArray[@]% }")
declare -p newArray

declare -a newArray=([0]="Some word." [1]="words" [2]="Foo bar baz" [3]="Hello w
orld" [4]="Singles")


Very informational. Unfortunately, your answer is accomplishing the opposite of what I am trying to do, which is to remove the non foo/bar elements.

Hauri: I found a solution based on your examples, thanks!

@kmt Sorry, answer edited:added reverse job in all 3 ways.

It's a simple error in your algorithm:
Since chomp can't be foo and bar at the same time, the command
[[ $chomp != "foo" ]] || [[ $chomp != "bar" ]]

will always be true. If you had written
[[ $chomp != "foo" ]] && [[ $chomp != "bar" ]]

you would select elements which are neither foo nor bar.
This derives from the formula from boolean algebra:
A ∨ B = ¬A ∧ ¬B


good explanation of my bad logic. I tried this and it still did not work for reasons unknown to me. Please see my next post.

A simpler solution to your problem can be implemented by using a temporary array to hold the array elements to be kept, and by taking advantage of the pattern matching and logical operators available with the [[ ... ]] command.
This Shellcheck-clean program demonstrates the idea:
#! /bin/bash -p

array=(8669648574foo 86696485745u 231649bar 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t)

tmparr=()
for v in "${array[@]}"; do
    [[ $v == *foo || $v == *bar ]] && tmparr+=( "$v" )
done
array=( "${tmparr[@]}" )

declare -p array

The program outputs:
declare -a array=([0]="8669648574foo" [1]="231649bar" [2]="8594792682foo")


declare -p var is one of the best ways to display the value of any variable because it displays it in an unambiguous way that can be used as shell code.


As I mentioned in my first post, I also tried using unset:
    for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        chomp=${array[i]: -3}
        echo chomp: $chomp
        if [ $chomp != "foo" ] || [ $chomp != "bar" ]; then
            echo "i: $i, element: ${array[i]}"
            unset array[$i]
        fi
    done
    array=( "${array[@]}" )
    echo "Fourth run: ${array[@]}"

Output: not expected
chomp: foo
i: 0, element: 8669648574foo
chomp: 45u
i: 1, element: 86696485745u
chomp: bar
i: 2, element: 231649bar
Fourth run: 23164919a1 8594792682foo 859479268209t # not expected

Changing that to && also did not work as expected:
    for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)); do
        chomp=${array[i]: -3}
        echo chomp: $chomp
        if [ $chomp != "foo" ] && [ $chomp != "bar" ]; then
            echo "i: $i, element: ${array[i]}"
            unset array[$i]
        fi
    done
    array=( "${array[@]}" )
    echo "Fifth run: ${array[@]}"

Output: extra unwanted element
chomp: foo
chomp: 45u
i: 1, element: 86696485745u
chomp: bar
chomp: 9a1
i: 3, element: 23164919a1
Fifth run: 8669648574foo 231649bar 8594792682foo 859479268209t

Found a solution (indirect expansion - thanks to F. Hauri):
    for i in ${!array[@]}; do
        chomp=${array[i]: -3}
        echo chomp: $chomp
        if [ $chomp != "foo" ] || [ $chomp != "bar" ]; then
            echo "i: $i, element: ${array[i]}"
            unset array[$i]
        fi
    done
    array=( "${array[@]}" )
    echo "Sixth run: ${array[@]}"

Output: expected result
chomp: foo
chomp: 45u
i: 1, element: 86696485745u
chomp: bar
chomp: 9a1
i: 3, element: 23164919a1
chomp: foo
chomp: 09t
i: 5, element: 859479268209t
Sixth run: 8669648574foo 231649bar 8594792682foo


When you unset an array element you reduce the number of elements (${#array[@]} in this case) by one, so the loop terminates before it gets to the maximum array index.  One way to fix the problem is to iterate on the list of array indexes (for i in "${!array[@]}"; do ...).

Please read [answer] and take the [tour] and note well that this is not a discussion forum. Do not use the answer section to provide "updated" information. If you wish to go back and forth with others to figure out a solution to your problem, please use a different site. If you wish to use Stack Overflow, you are expected to ask one, specific, properly focused question at a time - and it is your responsibility before posting to isolate a proper [mre] for debugging issues or specification for how-to questions.
